# Algorithm to guess which array element has its index (position) changed inside the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, compare, indexof

I've been looking for a while at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3476672/1705922) but all i could find there as results of comparaison between two arrays are which elements were added or removed.

What i need is to just guess which element has moved from an index to another.

Example: let's take the following array:

```
let array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
```

The 'E' element will move from the 4th index to the 2nd index and we wil get :

```
 let array2 = ['A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'D', 'F'];
```

I need a function that returns which element has changed , its new index in the new array2 and its old index in the array1;

I've made such as algo in the past which roughly (from what i remember now) consists of looking for the first different element between both arrays then to check the sequence behind it to guess if the diff element found is itself the moved one or the one which took its place.

So before rewritting it , i wished i could find one ready to use ;)

Comment: _"So before rewritting it , i wished i could find one ready to use ;)"_ ... whoever is going to answer either has to write it too (likely) or has exactly such an algorithm at hand (less likely). Maybe the OP shows a little effort by posting the former algorithm and the attempt made in order to adapt it. If the audience sees where the OP might got stuck there will be quite some people happy with helping the OP.  ... first hint ... `Let` should be all lowercase.

Comment: @PeterSeliger i didn't understand all you said but i'm going to share the algo once its done ;)

Comment: Compare the elements in pairs and detect the first and second discrepancies.

Comment: The approach is as follows ... (1) iterate one of the arrays, preferably the current one. (2) for each current item/value get its index from the recent array ... and ... (3) compare this item's/value's current index to its recent index. (4) in case both indices do not equal (including a recent index of `-1` due to a removed value/item) create a state like object with data of the value and the indices and push it into an result array.

Comment: I took this as a two part answer. Part one is how to get a data set that you can make guesses on. Part two is how to make those guesses. That is what I did. When it comes to guessing there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the full requirements are, but this will detect forward and backwards movement as well as character swaps. It will work on any order, but its prediction on what changed gets less accurate the more changes that occur in a row.
Here is a sample that uses a dictionary:

```js
const array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'];
const array2 = ['A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'G', 'K' , 'J'];
let globalOffset = 0;
let currentSuspect = "";
var dict = new Object();
array1.forEach((char, index) => {
  dict[char] = index;
});
array2.forEach((char, index) => {
  dict[char] = dict[char] - index;
});

let offset = 0;
let prevValue = 0;
Object.entries(dict).forEach((entry, index) => {
  const [key, value] = entry;
  
  switch(true){
    case offset === 0 && value < -1:
      console.log(`The character ${key} had its index moved forward by ${Math.abs(value)}! \n New index: ${index + Math.abs(value)} - Old index: ${index}`);
      break;
    case offset < 0 && value > 1:
      console.log(`The character ${key} had its index moved backwards by ${value}! \n New index: ${index + offset} - Old index: ${index}`);
      break;
    case prevValue === -1 && offset === -1 && value === 1:
      console.log(`The characters ${key} and ${array2[index]} were swapped!`);
      break;
  }
  prevValue = value;
  offset += value;
});
```

Comment: there is an issue with handling characters that appears twice

Comment: @iamzouz I wrote this to the specifications of the OP, and handling double letters was not a requirement, apologies.

Comment: how would one go about it with duplicates?

Comment: @iamzouz please attempt, if you are having trouble take your modified code and ask a new question please. You can let me know here and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is as follows ...

- iterate one of the arrays, preferably the current one.
- for each current item/value get its index from the recent array ...
- ... and compare this item's/value's current index to its recent index.
- in case both indices do not equal (including a recent index of `-1` due to a removed value/item) create a state like object with data of the value and the indices and push it into the result array.

The implementation is based on [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) where on would process the current item array and would pass the recent item array as part of a accumulator/collector as the reducer function's [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value).

```js
function collectPositionChange({ recent, result }, value, currentIdx) {
  const recentIdx = recent.indexOf(value);
  if (recentIdx !== currentIdx) {

    result.push({ value, currentIdx, recentIdx });
  }
  return { recent, result };
}
const recentItems = ['A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'D', 'F'];
const currentItems = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

console.log(
  currentItems
    .reduce(collectPositionChange, { recent: recentItems, result: [] })
    .result
);
console.log(
  ['A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'F']
    .reduce(collectPositionChange, { recent: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], result: [] })
    .result
);
console.log(
  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    .reduce(collectPositionChange, { recent: ['A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'F'], result: [] })
    .result
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

// test 1 : moving 'B' from index 1 to index 3
let array2 = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'F'];

// test 2: moving 'E' from 4 to 1
// let array2 = ['A', 'E', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'];

// test 3 : moving 'A' from 0 to 5
// let array2 = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'A'];

function getMovedElementInfos(array1, array2) {
    let firstDiffElIndexInNewArray = array2.findIndex((el, elindx) => el !== array1[elindx]);
    let firstDiffElInNewArray = array2[firstDiffElIndexInNewArray];
    let nextElInNewArray = array2[firstDiffElIndexInNewArray + 1];
    let firstDiffElIndexInOldArray = array1.findIndex(el => el === firstDiffElInNewArray);
    let nextElInOldArray = array1[firstDiffElIndexInOldArray + 1];
    let movedEl, movedElFrom, movedElTo;
    if (nextElInNewArray === nextElInOldArray) {
        movedEl = array1[firstDiffElIndexInNewArray];
        movedElFrom = firstDiffElIndexInNewArray;
        movedElTo = array2.findIndex(el => el === movedEl);
    } else {
        movedEl = firstDiffElInNewArray;
        movedElFrom = firstDiffElIndexInOldArray;
        movedElTo = firstDiffElIndexInNewArray;
    }
    return {
        movedEl,
        movedElFrom,
        movedElTo
    }
}
const {
    movedEl,
    movedElFrom,
    movedElTo
} = getMovedElementInfos(array1, array2)

console.log('movedEl is: ', movedEl);
console.log('movedEl index in old array is: ', movedElFrom);
console.log('movedEl index in new array is: ', movedElTo);

console.log('array1[movedElFrom]: ', array1[movedElFrom]);
console.log('array2[movedElTo]: ', array2[movedElTo]);
```

Comment: Aren't there 3 items moved? `'B'`, `'C'` and `'D'`? I'm going to post my solution.

Comment: I needed to guess the minimum that has changed to be able to form the latter array from the former one , not everything that has changed. But thanks @PeterSeliger