# How to determine position change between two arrays with duplicates in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, data-structures

I have two arrays array1 and array2 in my Node.js application, both of which may contain duplicate elements. I need to calculate the position change for each element in array1 compared to array2. I know for sure that the arrays are of the same length and contain the same characters.
The position change is defined as the difference in index positions between the same element in the two arrays. However, since the arrays may contain duplicates, I cannot use the indexOf method to find the index of each element in array2 or use dictionaries.

```js
const array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'A'];
const array2 = ['A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'D', 'A' 'F'];
```

in this example, E had its index moved backwards by 2 positions and A (the second one) and F were swapped.

Here is what I tried after checking some [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72306682/algorithm-to-guess-which-array-element-has-its-index-position-changed-inside-t/72307685#72307685) :

```
    function collectPositionChange({
  recent,
  result
}, value, currentIdx) {
  const recentIdx = recent.indexOf(value);
  if (recentIdx !== currentIdx) {
    // calculate the difference in the indices
    const idxDiff = currentIdx - recentIdx;

    result.push({
      value,
      currentIdx,
      recentIdx,
      idxDiff,
    });

    // update the recent array
    recent.splice(recentIdx, 1); // remove the value from the recent array
    recent.splice(currentIdx - (idxDiff > 0 ? 1 : 0), 0, value); // insert the value at its new position

    if (idxDiff < -1) {
      console.log(`The value '${value}' moved backwards by ${Math.abs(idxDiff)} positions.`);
    } else if (idxDiff > 1) {
      console.log(`The value '${value}' moved frontwards by ${Math.abs(idxDiff)} positions.`);
    } else if (Math.abs(idxDiff) === 1) {
      const otherValue = recent[recentIdx];
      console.log(`The values '${value}' and '${otherValue}' were swapped.`);
    }
  }
  return {
    recent,
    result
  };
}
const array1 = ['A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'F'];
const array2 = ['B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'A'];

console.log(
  array1
  .reduce(collectPositionChange, {
    recent: array2,
    result: []
  })
  .result
);
```

Comment: you have to start by removing the ambiguities of duplicates, then the solution will be simple

Comment: So, what did you try by yourself ? what kind of result details are you expecting ? didn't tell us that you are expecting code for free!

Comment: I specified the results I am expecting to have... and as I said I tried to use a dict which is similar to the accepted answer in this question to calculate the offsets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72306682/algorithm-to-guess-which-array-element-has-its-index-position-changed-inside-t/72307685#72307685

Comment: it's not the same requirements. I have duplicate values as I said above.

Comment: you should have started by indicating the reference of this solution in your question... if not, I ask the question again, what have you tried to do by yourself? Nothing ?

Comment: how should the swap of 2 elements be indicated if they then undergo a shift; which makes this swap invisible?

Comment: and what do you mean by `I cannot use ...... dictionaries` ?